# Office365 REST API - fetch calendar event by event id

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get event by it's id with office365 REST API, but I'm receiving 404 error.

This is the url I'm using:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('{organizer email}')/Events('{eventId}')
```

Calendar fetching, event creation and deletion works as it should.

Comment: Maybe the event has been deleted? If you're sure that's not the case, then post the full URL you're using and ideally the JSON where you're getting this ID.

Comment: I found out that 'Id' of an event on Room calendar is not the same as on the creator's calendar. That is why I get 404 error. Only Id that is the same is iCalId.